# How to include JavaScript files into twig template using Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I can easily include CSS files into my twig template like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/user/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/user/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/user/css/main.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

But for my JavaScript files

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/user/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/user/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

The approach does not work. I tried to use `assetics` too, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you do app/console assets:install ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd recommend the Assetic approach. It's not exactly simple, but it gives you huge benefits.

First, embed your JS in a template like this:

```
{% block my_javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@FooBarBundle/Resources/public/js/foo.js'
        '@FooBarBundle/Resources/public/js/bar.js'

        filter='?uglifyjs2'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Add as many JS files as you like.

Now run the following on the command line:

```
app/console assetic:dump
```

In your `dev` environment, this will generate a copy of your JS files within the document root. In your `prod`, this will generate *one* combined file in the doc root – the first benefit.

To have your files generated automatically in the background while you edit them, run the following from the command line, and keep it running until you're done (cancel then with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>):

```
app/console assetic:watch --force
```

(The `--force` option causes Assetic to generate the files even if it there don't seem to be any modifications.)

Another benefit is the `filter='uglifyjs2'` statement: It causes the files to be "compressed" with UgilifyJS, which loads much faster.

[Read more about using Assetic for JS and CSS in Symfony2 in the cookbook.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sadly, I really have to specify each file, otherwise jQuery will not be called first. I have a question. Can I put the CSS and JS files directly into /web? Or is it really necessary to put inside of Bundle's public folder?

Comment: If you want to have jQ loaded first, try renaming the file to `000.jquery.js` (just a guess, don't know if they are included in alphabetical order).

Comment: You should not put JS/CSS directly into `./web`. Better put them into the `public` folder and have them copied with `app/console assets:install`. But in this case, the public path will be something like `/bundles/yourbundle/css/…`. This, however, has nothing to do with Assetic, it's the Symfony-internal way of managing assets. (A bit confusing, but you'll get the idea.)